# Why isn't my Tailwind CSS setup working with Google Chrome?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm new to Tailwind and my setup works on Firefox, but not with Google Chrome. Is there some sort of webkit issue that I might be missing? I have tested my code on various versions. Weirdly with dev tools it does work on Chrome. However the deploy doesn't work on Google or Android phone. All styles are applied except the resizing elements, so my phone just displays a monitor webpage.

```js
  function Header() {
    return (
    <>
      <section
        id='hero'
        className='px-4 py-8 mx-auto sm:max-w-xl md:max-w-full lg:max-w-screen-xl md:px-24 lg:px-8'
      >
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-between w-full mb-10 lg:flex-row'>
          <div className='mb-16 lg:mb-0 lg:max-w-lg lg:pr-5 lg:pl-5'>
            <article className='max-w-xl mb-6'>
              <div>
                <h4 className='inline-block font-semibold tracking-wider uppercase text-eco-green rounded-full'>
                  Brand new web project
                </h4>
              </div>
              <h1 className='text-eco-green font-extrabold text-6xl pb-6 md:py-4 text-center md:text-left'>
                myecoapp
              </h1>
              <h2 className='font-sans text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 sm:text-4xl sm:leading-none max-w-lg mb-6'>
                Help The Planet <br className='hidden md:block' />
                by existing{' '}
                <span className='inline-block text-deep-purple-accent-400'>
                  and clicking
                </span>
              </h2>
              <p className='text-gray-700 text-base md:text-lg'>
                Help the environment from anywhere for free! At home or at any
                event. Use our apps to earn while you relax. We have done what
                we can to provide entertainment for you. Check it out below.
              </p>
            </article>
            <div className='flex items-center space-x-3'>
              <CTA />
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Phones */}
          <div className='flex h-full items-center justify-center lg:w-1/2'>
            <div className='w-2/5'>
              <img
                className='object-cover'
                src='https://kitwind.io/assets/kometa/one-girl-phone.png'
                alt=''
              />
            </div>
            <div className='w-5/12 -ml-16 lg:-ml-32'>
              <img
                className='object-cover'
                src='https://kitwind.io/assets/kometa/two-girls-phone.png'
                alt=''
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )}
```

Comment: May be you miss to include the css in the html file, and is showing in chrome because is cached. To make sure of this share with us the code where you include the css file.

Comment: What is not working? Is everything unstyled in chrome?

Comment: all style still applies except the resizing elements. so my phone just display a monitor webpage. but my nav bar is still styled perfectly

Comment: I have the same problem: https://miuler-medical-001.web.app/histories